# Placing Navigation Guards

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

In some tutorial I found they placed Navigation Guards in `main.js` file. Others placed it in `router/index.js` file.

In which file can I write Navigation Guards `Router.beforeEach((to, from, next)` ?

Comment: Basically it can be anywhere where you can import your route file

Comment: It's a flexibility that Vue Router provides. You can place your navigation guards anywhere in your app, even in the components as the documentation states,

`Finally, you can directly define route navigation guards inside route components (the ones passed to the router configuration) with the following options`

Answer (score 0):

You can write the guards in your `router.js` if you want. Just import the `Router` in your `main.js` file. Example code:

```
// router.js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

const Router = new VueRouter({
    // your code
});

Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // your code

    next();
});

export default Router;


// main.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from './router.js';

const app = new Vue({
    router: Router
    // your code
});
```